# Find POI along a Google Maps route? (Android)

Tags: android, database, google-maps, geolocation, routes

[doing "points of interest along a route" in google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835377/doing-points-of-interest-along-a-route-in-google-maps)
This would fit perfectly to my question...... But its not suitable for an android activity :/

So I start copiing the question now... just wait :D... aargh! Done!

> I need to allow travelers to use google maps to plot a route, and then
>   query my database of points of interest (let's say, McDonald's
>   locations) and then show all of these locations that are within a mile
>   or two of the route they will be taking. The question is, how do I
>   efficiently take the "driving directions" information that comes back
>   from google (essentially an array of lat/long pairs), and turn that
>   into an sql query to get locations that fall within a certain distance
>   from the route? 
>   ...and then put the whole thing into my android app?

I dont get it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first:

1) do you have latlng (geolocations) variable type in your database?

If answer(1) == yes:
   Calculate and query your database: D²=(Xb-Xa)²+(Yb-Ya)² along each of your Xa,Ya route points to discover the POIs (Ya,Yb) within Distance = D.

Comment: But how may I figure out what my route points are? It should be done with PHP you know? (sry for answering so late)