# Google Places or Maps - points along a route

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, maps, google-places-api, proximity

I have a programming task related to maps.
We are going to ask people where they live, where they work and potentially other common 'locations' they drive to. We will then map the routes to/from these locations (likely via google maps/places api). We then need to figure out if the person driving these routes has a likelihood of driving past certain locations (a list of ~500 specific landmarks we'll specify). I am thinking I can achieve this with google maps/places, but I'm relatively new to mapping related tasks.

Is what I am saying achievable via these apis and can you direct me to any docs or tutorials?

I'm thinking that we decide whether a person 'drives past' a certain location can be achieved by calculating distance b/w landmark AND the closest point to it on the route(s), I'm just not sure HOW to do this (or if that is the best solution).

Comment: [doing “points of interest along a route” in google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835377/doing-points-of-interest-along-a-route-in-google-maps?rq=1)