# Google Maps:How to get points along the route in google maps, server side?

Tags: javascript, php, ruby, node.js, google-maps

*Note: So the question title looks a bit similar to other questions on Stackoverflow, but its not quite same. Read on.*

As it is clear that I want to get the lat long using from google maps api along the route but I want to do it on the server side (may be using Ruby, PHP, NodeJS)?

I can do it very well on client side using GMAPS V3 api and with [v3_epoly.js](http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/v3_epoly.js) and [here](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip.htm) is very good example of finding lat long and plotting some animation, which is perfect. It returns lat long along the route at a particular distance.

I want to get the lat long on the server side. How do I do it? As I see there is no lib or google api available in Ruby(or any other server side lang). How do I use [v3_epoly.js](http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/v3_epoly.js)?

So I have the solution but I want it server side as I ll be using these to serve my apps. I don't want it client side.

You can get the route using google direction api.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=28.700825,77.136429&destination=28.461790,77.053457&key=API_KEY

I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsRequests

Comment: @pablochan I know about directions API but the question is getting the lat long in between 2 points not the point of interest which is already available in directions api. So think of 10 miles stretch straight road, what is the the lat long after 1 mile from the starting point?

Comment: There's a field in the response: overview_polyline. It contains a path between the from and to points. You just have to decode it: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm

Comment: @pablochan `overview_polyline` worked for me. Please post it as answer, i ll accept.

Comment: follow this link. you will get your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42157236/6070229

Answer (score 1):

Needed to the same thing and after a bit of looking around I found [turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) which provides a similar functionality via [along()](http://turfjs.org/docs/#along):

Here is the example from documentation:

```
var line = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [-77.031669, 38.878605],
      [-77.029609, 38.881946],
      [-77.020339, 38.884084],
      [-77.025661, 38.885821],
      [-77.021884, 38.889563],
      [-77.019824, 38.892368]
    ]
  }
};

var along = turf.along(line, 1, 'miles');

var result = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [line, along]
};
```

It uses [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/), but it shouldn't be hard to plugin coordinates from Google Maps.